# Change an image in a UITableViewCell without reloading cell

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I'm writing an iPhone app with a UITableView as the primary user interface.  Each section consists of two rows, a header and the body.  When the user clicks on the header, I remove the second row by changing the numberOfRowsInSection value:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    cbwComponent *comp = [_componentController objectInListAtIndex:section];
    if([comp hasContentsView] && !comp.contentsHidden){
        return 2;
    }else
        return 1;
}
```

When the user selects the header, I'm using the following code:

```
comp.contentsHidden = YES;
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:indexPath.section], nil];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

It's working great, with a nice smooth fade effect.  The problem is, I'm trying to add an indicator in the header cell (row 0) that changes when it's clicked on.  To change that image I have to refresh the top row as well as the second row, which makes the transition look bad (well, not nearly as smooth).  Is there a way to change the image in a UITableViewCell without refreshing the cell?

Thanks

EDIT: I figured it out! You can maintain the smooth transition as long as you reload that first row before you make the change to the second row. It has to be called inside of [tableView beginUpdates];

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates]; 
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
... 
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could also subclass a tableview cell and implement a view transition in it that can be called from your view controller. You could then call that without having to reload the cell.

```
[(YourCustomCell*)[tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfYourCell] fadeInIndicator];
```